# Book about children who sneak onto a rocket headed to Ganymede

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading a book in primary school about children going to Ganymede but I can't remember what it's called at all.

I can't remember much about the book; I seem to remember that the children snuck on the rocket ship, but that's all I really remember. We read it in 2003 so it was definitely published then or before.

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  This is very little information; could you add any other details to improve your chances of finding an answer?  Thanks

Comment: I can't remember much about the book, I seem to remember that the children snuck on the rocketship but that's all really. We read it in 2003 so it was definitely published then or before.

Comment: All the information you can provide helps!

Comment: @Emily Welcome to SFF.SE. Please edit all information you can think of into your question, not in comments (comments are meant to be temporary). I've edited your comment into your question for you. Please take a look at the [help] for more information.

Comment: Cover design?  Format (a single novel, or a collection of stories)?  Names?  Anything?

Comment: No sneaking, but [Farmer In The Sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farmer_in_the_Sky) is the first thing that comes to mind for Ganymede.

Comment: Lester Del Rey's 1963 Outpost of Jupiter has high-school aged characters and takes place on Ganymede.  Post more memories if they arise.

Comment: I'm sure I read this book too! I'm also struggling to identify it. The book was a **single novel**. The **two children were a boy and a girl**. As I remember, Ganymede's canyons turn out to be inhabited by **lifeforms that appear to be tree stumps**, except they can move around using their roots as legs. I'm also fairly sure that although they're perceived as hostile by the children, they turn out to be friendly. (Of course that memory could be reconstructed from surmise, given how that would be a common formula in many children's books.) ...

Comment: ... I was born in 1982 and I read the book in primary school (UK), which means **July 1993 at the latest**. So that knocks another ten years off the earliest possible publishing date.

I would guess that the **reading age is probably about 8 to 12**.

I am bookmarking this page, so that I can return and add any further details that I might remember -- or indeed the answer if I find it.

Answer (score 5):

**Potential answer**, but I can't find a more complete synopsis

EDIT: Google Books allows a limited search-inside-book feature and this is *definitely* the correct answer for my half-remembered book. I hope it is what Emily was searching for, too. I can even confirm that the tree-stump-alikes were called the Soshtii.

It might be *Ghost Ship to Ganymede* by Robert Swindells. The only synopsis I can find for that title is:

> Fay, Tom and Grover stow away on a spaceship and find to their horror that they are en route to unexplored Ganymede, a moon of Jupiter.

(from Google Books)

Well that fits, *as far as it goes*.

I could have forgotten a third character. Mentioning that Ganymede is unexplored is a favourable point, and sets this book apart from many others; it certainly wasn't set on a well developed Ganymede as most stories seem to be. I forgot to be clear that **the lifeforms in the canyons are previously unknown**, and discovered by the children.

Robert Swindells apparently writes for the right age group, too. *Room 13* was also his, for instance.

I can't find a library copy of *Ghost Ship to Ganymede*, a download (legal or otherwise), or a reasonably priced hard copy. I can only find some that are, for whatever reason, pushing the £1000 mark.

I wonder if the synopsis rings true with Emily as well? Perhaps she could perform an image search for that title, and see if any covers look familiar?

I'll also see if I can hunt down a copy by ringing some bookshops.

Must, consolidate, early, memories, or, might, never, punctuate, properly, again!

Comment: What is your source for the synopsis you quoted?

Comment: Just Google books (added in editing)

Answer (score 0):

*[Farmer in the Sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farmer_in_the_Sky)* by Robert A. Heinlein

> The story is set in a future, overcrowded Earth, where food is carefully rationed. Teenager William (Bill) Lermer lives with his widower father, George. George decides to emigrate to the farming colony on Ganymede, one of Jupiter's moons. After marrying Molly Kenyon, George embarks with Bill and Molly's daughter Peggy on the 'torchship' Mayflower. On the journey, Bill saves his bunkmates from asphyxiation by improvising a patch when a meteor punctures their compartment. During the trip all the children attend class; also, to combat the boredom of the long trip, the Boy Scouts among the passengers form troops.

Comment: How? Why? What points match the OP's criteria? Could you please elaborate. Merely saying *what* the answer doesn't help others find out *why* it's the answer, especially if someone else is also looking for the same story.

Comment: This would be a much better answer if it explained why this might be the right story.

Comment: I honestly don't know if my edit really makes it match much better, but it at least indicates that there's a Ganymede trip by kids. No stowing away, though.